# Using arrays in regular expressions?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

Does anyone know if there is a way to use an array in a regular expression? suppose I want to find out if `somefile.txt` contains one of an array's elements. Obviously the code below doesn't work, but is there something similar that does work?

```
array = [thing1 thing2 thing3]
file = File.open("somefile.txt")

file.each_do |line|
if /array/.match(line)
puts line
end
```

Basically I've got a file that contains a list of words that I need to use as search terms in another large file, and I'd like to avoid something like this:

```
($somefile =~ /(thing1|thing2|thing3)/)
```

Comment: Your statement of the question is wrong. You don't want to use an array in regex, you want to express alternatives in regex (which is given as an array).

Comment: But I think I do want to use an array? Basically I've got a file that contains a list of words that I need to use as search terms in another large file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-c-union), it returns a `Regexp` that matches any of the given regex. The argument patterns could be either `String` or `Regexp`:

```
Regexp.union(%w(thing1 thing2 thing3))
#=> /thing1|thing2|thing3/
```

or

```
Regexp.union(/thing1/, /thing2/, /thing3/)
#=> /(?-mix:thing1)|(?-mix:thing2)|(?-mix:thing3)/
```

Comment: Could I use the contents of my array to populate that regexp.union somehow?

Comment: @RachaelHardison You mean `Regexp.union(array)`? Sure, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
x = ['qwe', 'asd', 'zxc']
file = File.open("somefile.txt")
regexp = /(#{x.join '|'})/
file.each_do |line|
  puts line if regexp.match(line)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I am much closer! However, I think I'm missing something here. When I run this it doesn't actually output anything, it just moves to the next command line, so I think it worked, but just didn't print anything?